# adding column to data frame based on values from a separate table in r

Tags: r

I would like to add a column to this data frame, df1

```
   B    C
   jon   joe
   bob  stan
   ryan will
```

where values assigned to each individual are stored in df2,

```
name score time 
jon  3     7  
joe  8     6 
bob  1     4 
stan 3     3
ryan 13    9
will 3     4
```

The new column should take the difference between the two individuals score resulting in the data frame, df3,

```
B     C      D
jon   joe   -5
bob  stan   -2
ryan will   10
```

I have been able to make the whole column the first difference (jon and joe) with
`mutate(df1,(df2[df2$name==df1[1,1],2])-df2[df2$name== df1[1,2] ,2])`
but cannot make it repeated for each pair of individuals.

Thank you!

Comment: For the `df1`, the data is not complete. which column correspond to 'score', 'name' in that

Answer (score 0):

We can create a named vector and then do the `match` by looping over the columns and `Reduce` the corresponding values by taking the `-`

```
nm1 <- with(df2, setNames(score, name))
df1$D <- Reduce(`-`, lapply(df1, function(x) nm1[x]))
```

-output

```
df1
#     B    C  D
#1  jon  joe -5
#2  bob stan -2
#3 ryan will 10
```

---

Or another option is to use `match`

```
Reduce(`-`, lapply(df1, function(x) df2$score[match(x, df2$name)]))
#[1] -5 -2 10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(B = c("jon", "bob", "ryan"), C = c("joe", "stan", 
"will")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("jon", "joe", "bob", "stan", "ryan", 
"will"), score = c(3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 13L, 3L), time = c(7L, 6L, 
4L, 3L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: I get error: "only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts" when running this with my code?

Comment: @orange_man can you please check with the data in my post.  It is working fine for me

Comment: it works when I use the data in your post but not when I use my data

Comment: @orange_man i copied your example to create the data.  Can you check `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` for your dataset.  I have `character` class for those 'B', 'C' columns in df1 and 'name' column in df2

Comment: It might be something with data I am actually working with, I used the above example to represent my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @orange_man can you update your post with `dput(yourdata)` for both examples so that I get the structure of your data for testing

Comment: the three columns in my data are all `character`

Comment: @orange_man can you update with `dput` on your post so that I can test it

Comment: @orange_man what is the value for 'nm1' from my first line

Comment: I actually am unsure of how to use `dput`

Comment: @orange_man Just do `dput(df1)` and copy the output from the console

Comment: some of my values in nm1 are negative. might this be the issue

Comment: @orange_man As long as those values are numeric, there shouldn't be an issue though

Comment: @orange_man e.g. `Reduce(`-`, lapply(df1, function(x) -nm1[x]))#
 jon  bob ryan
   5    2  -10 `

Comment: @orange_man may be you can try with `match` i.e. `Reduce(`-`, lapply(df1, function(x) df2$score[match(x, df2$name)]))`

Comment: @orange_man for the first data, I find the dput is not complete.  If you have bigger dataset, just take the head of the data to get the dput. i.e. `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))`

Comment: @orange_man sorry, i have to leave now.  The data is not complete  for 'df1' so it can't be tested

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
df3 <- df1
df3[] <- df2$score[match(unlist(df1), df2$name)]
df1$D <- df3$B - df3$C
df1

#     B    C  D
#1  jon  joe -5
#2  bob stan -2
#3 ryan will 10
```